# Не запускается эмулятор android studio. AMD (x64)/ Windows7

Tags: android-studio

Не устанавливается Android Emulator Hypervision Driver for AMD processing

Выдает ошибку:
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors

При запуске выдает:
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors is not installed.

Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors for better emulation performance.

---

Гипер-V к сожалению нет, так как у меня 7-ка стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте войти в SDK менеджер и установить Android Emulator HV for AMD.
[image: amd]

а так же перейдите в Панель управления> Программы> Включение и отключение компонентов Windows. найдите там AMD HyperVision(что то в этом роде) и включите его. Если она горит серым значит в биосе не включена виртуализация. Смотрите в инструкций материнской платы как ее включить.
Если это вам не помогло проверьте разрядность эмулятора, и совпадает ли он с вашим компьютером. А также проверьте хватает ли ОЗУ для эмулятора в окне создания/изменения эмулятора

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь эмулятор появляется и пропадает. Вылетает ошибка: The emulator process for AVD JFGHFGHFH was killed